# How do I get k3s to authenticate with Docker Hub?

Tags: dockerhub, k3s

In `jornalctl -u k3s`, I see a bunch of errors like this

> 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit

When I check the associate pods, I see

> Error from server (BadRequest): container "foo" in pod "bar" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image

How can I set up k3s to use an authenticate login to DockerHub? I don't see a `docker login`, and I've tried probably 20 different things none of which worked. I can confirm this username and password works with [`--creds` to either `crictl` or `ctr`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16152/18965). But it doesn't work when I try to put it in a config file. I've tried to playing with

- `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` and restarting.
- that seems to generate a new `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml`, I've tried playing with that file too directly

None of this seems to make any difference. I've tried testing with `k3s kubectl run` and also with [`k3s crt` and `k3s crictl` without providing `--creds`](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/16152/18965), and none of these change the error that's returned.

My token has full access at https://hub.docker.com/settings/security

Answer (score 2):

1. Update your `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` to

   ```yaml
   configs:
     registry-1.docker.io:
       auth:
         username: evancarroll
         password: TOKENHIDDEN
   ```
2. Restart k3s, `sudo systemctl force-reload k3s`.

You can confirm the changes were accepted by checking that your key exists in `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml`.