# Does /etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml affect `k3s ctr` and `k3s crictl`?

Tags: configuration, authentication, k3s, containerd

`k3s ctr` launches the contianerd CLI, and `k3s crictl` is the CRI cli. I'm told you configure k3s authentication to the image registries using [`/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml`](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry/). Does this yaml file configure containerd, and CRI such that these commands no longer require `--creds`?

```shell
k3s crictl pull     --creds "evancarroll:$TOKEN" docker.io/alpine:3
k3s ctr images pull --creds "evancarroll:$TOKEN" docker.io/library/alpine:3
```

And can just be

```shell
k3s crictl pull     docker.io/alpine:3
k3s ctr images pull docker.io/library/alpine:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I got from [Rancher Developer Brandon D in their slack](https://webpros.slack.com/archives/C02T5F4PFJ7/p1641935253158000)

> `ctr` and `crictl` both interact with containerd, via different apis. ctr uses the containerd native api, and crictl uses the CRI api. The `registries.yaml` config is used by containerd itself, and will be honored no matter what it is that does the pull or how.